# newsavebox named after counter

Tags: macros, expansion

I am trying to write a macro creting automatically a certain number of saveboxes. Therefore I would like to use the concatination of the value of a string and a counter to name the saveboxes. I tried the following and latex complains "Missing Contorl sequence inserted" every time I try to use it.

```
\newcounter{saveboxCount}
\newsavebox{MyString\alpha{saveboxCount}}
```

Comment: The main problem with your use of `\newsavebox` is that it requires a control sequence rather than just a string. Hence the use of `\csname ...\endcsname` to construct the control sequence.

Comment: @Werner: I noticed that for `newsavebox` it works if I add the backslash `\`, however I have issues with actually using the box later.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The following will create saveboxes `\MyStringa` to `\MyStringz`:

```
\makeatletter
\count@=0
\loop\ifnum\count@<26
  \advance\count@\@ne
  \expandafter\newsavebox\csname MyString\@alph\count@\endcsname
\repeat
\makeatother
```

It's also simple (even simpler) with `expl3`:

```latex
\usepackage{expl3}

\ExplSyntaxOn

% loop from 1 to 26, #1 denotes the current value in the cycle
\int_step_inline:nn { 26 }
 {
  \exp_args:Nc \newsavebox { MyString \int_to_alph:n { #1 } }
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff
```

With `\exp_args:Nc` we jump over `\newsavebox` and form a control sequence token from the braced argument before `\newsavebox` is actually performed.

In the log file we'll find something like

```latex
\MyStringa=\box46
\MyStringb=\box47
\MyStringc=\box48
[...similar lines...]
\MyStringy=\box70
\MyStringz=\box71
```

confirming that the allocations have been performed.

Comment: why are you using `\count@` instead of newcounter? Also any idea why I am seeing errors for `\newcommand{\floatRow@resetList}`?

Comment: @ted: Is `\floatRow@resetList` already defined?

Comment: @Werner: no. I have no idea how to write a package but thought I found something I could work on, and wanted a namespace of my own, e.g. `\floatRow@` (I think i should go for something else due to the package of that name), but for simplicity I started with just one tex file, so it is in my main document.

Comment: @egreg: I did some research, you use a [tex counter](http://www.texdev.net/2009/11/17/tex-counts-and-latex-counters/), while this article explained the reasons, I do not understand what `@` translates to since count expects a number after all I know. WOuld you enlighten me on its meaning in the conjunction with count?

Comment: `@` is just part of the counter name that @egreg is using.  In the context of `\makeatletter` the `@` is treated just like any other letter of the alphabet

Comment: @A.Ellett: I thought counters must be named by numbers, but aparently that is wrong?.

Comment: @Werner: Turned out the @nameing issue came from an accidential inversion of `makeatletter`/`makeatother`, therefore I removed it from the question but since I can't edit my comments anymore I will leave it here.

Comment: @ted `\count@` is to be considered a scratch count register, for temporary usage. The `@` is part of the name, since we're under `\makeatletter`. You can use `\@tempcnta` or `\@tempcntb` for the same purpose.

Comment: @egreg where can I find a good overview of special register names and special shortcuts (I assume `\@ne` is a shortcut for `1\relax`?

Comment: @ted `\@ne` comes from `\chardef\@ne=1`. All these registers and constants are explained in `source2e.pdf`

Answer (score 2):

With `xsavebox`, boxes don't need to be declared but are created on the fly, and they are addressed by name, rather than by command:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xsavebox}
\usepackage{pgffor}

\begin{document}

\noindent\foreach \idx in {a,b,...,z} {%
  \xsbox{myString \idx}{That's what I saved: \idx}%
}%
%
\foreach \idx in {a,b,...,z} {%
  \noindent\xusebox{myString \idx}\par
}

\end{document}
```

Pkg `xsavebox` allocates 2 TeX box registers in total:

```
\l_xsb_box=\box45
\l_xsb_raw_box=\box46
```