# correct usage of \@namedef and \@nameuse

Tags: macros

In a [previous question I asked how to generate multiple saveboxes in a loop](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/126255/19326). The answer build around `csname` and the part inside `csname` is rather long and I need the name several times (create the box, fill the box, get properties and use it). Therefore I would like to shorten this. I tried

```
\makeatletter
...
\@namedef{saveBox}{<what was inbetween \csname \endcsname>}
...
\expandafter\newsavebox\@nameuse{saveBox}
...
\makeatother
```

which is not working for me. A short background information on the inner workings/general intended use would be a bonus.

---

The awnser leaves me with one issue, I can't get the `\def` version to work with a direct version, see example for clarification:

```
\def\floatRow@currentSaveBox{floatRow@savebox\alph{floatRow@rowImageCount}}
%\expandafter\newsavebox\csname\floatRow@currentSaveBox\endcsname   %works
\expandafter\newsavebox\csname{}floatRow@savebox\alph{floatRow@saveboxCount}\endcsname  %gives mising number error
```

I assume that my separation of `\commandName` and the string `floatRow@savebox` is wrong. Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass{report}
\begin{document}
\newcounter{c}
\def\currentSBox{prefix\alph{c}}
\expandafter\newsavebox\csname\currentSBox\endcsname
\expandafter\savebox\csname\currentSBox\endcsname{dummy}
\expandafter\usebox\csname\currentSBox\endcsname
\expandafter\usebox\csname{}prefix\alph{c}\endcsname
\end{document}
```

Comment: I suggest to take a look into the `etoolbox` package. It provides a much cleaner and more complete interface for the construction of command sequences without using kernel primitives.

Comment: `\@nameuse{saveBox}` needs two expansions to give you the name `\saveBox` (`\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\newsavebox\@nameuse{saveBox}`) but that won't work either: `\newsavebox` will complain: `! LaTeX Error: Command \saveBox already defined.`

Comment: Maybe you can explain a bit what it really is you want to achieve?

Comment: @cgnieder this is my attempt at writing code to automatically solve the issue from here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/125675/19326. For that I need a macro which generates saveboxes for every image on the row and store it there. Then I can calculate the scales needed hoepfully write them to an aux file and apply them in the next pass. This is for the first step, creating and writing stuff to saveboxes. Do you need to see the corresponding code mess (you have been warnder ;) ) or is there a general explanation for the intended use?

Comment: @cgnieder: also why does `\@nameuse` require two expansions?

Comment: `\@nameuse{foo}` expands to `\csname foo\endcsname` which then expands to `\foo`

Comment: @cgnieder doesn`t `\@namedef` define `saveBox` already as `\csname foo\endcsname` already, what is the purpose of `\@nameuse`, just to add the `\csname` wrapper? why cant I use `\saveBox` directly then? And will `edef` or `\csedef` from etoolbox fix the issue?

Comment: @Daniel: Would you mind giving an example on how to use etoolbox? In my previous comment I stated my best guest but I am not sure, and the documentation is very brief and due to the lack of examples to a novice like me.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/9906/discussion-between-ted-and-cgnieder)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Let's look at what is happening here. The construct

```
\@namedef{saveBox}{<what was inbetween \csname \endcsname>}
```

is defining `\saveBox` as a macro with replacement text `<what was inbetween \csname \endcsname>`. That's because `\@namedef` is defined as

```
#1->\expandafter\def\csname #1\endcsname
```

That means that what it does is first convert `#1` (`saveBox` in your case) into a control sequence (`\saveBox` here), the apply `\def`. So it's become the same as doing

```
\def\saveBox{<what was inbetween \csname \endcsname>}
```

This is a useful-enough thing to do, but in the current case isn't actually what you want!

The second line

```
\expandafter\newsavebox\@nameuse{saveBox}
```

is going to fail badly for several reasons, as comments already mention. `\@nameuse` is a wrapper around `\csname ...\endcsname`, and so with only one expansion you get to

```
\newsavebox\csname saveBox\endscsname
```

which tries to define `\csname` as a new box!. If we do two expansions we get to

```
\newsavebox\saveBox
```

which is still wrong as you've already defined `\saveBox` as a macro.

Based on the linked question, what you seem to want is more of the form

```
\def\my@name{MyString\@alph\count@}
\expandafter\newsavebox\csname\my@name\endcsname
...
\expandafter\usebox\csname\my@name\endcsname
```

*i.e.* to save the form of the name in a macro and reuse that.

---

You may wonder what `\@nameuse` is for, as it seems to make things more not less complex (`\@namedef` is handy). This is at least partly historical: when LaTex2e was written, tokens were very 'expensive', so the saving of `\@nameuse` (one token) over `\csname ...\endcsname` (two tokens) was worth making when you look at all of the uses in the kernel. Today, that's much less important, although there is an argument that

```
\def\foo#1{% Some function
  ...
  \@nameuse{my@#1}%
}
```

is clearer than

```
\def\foo#1{% Some function
  ...
  \csname my@#1\endcsname
}
```

as it shows up that something is being used rather than say defined by name.

---

Using `\@namedef` is more common, as it allows easy construction of 'on the fly' names. For example, we can imagine storing some user input:

```
\newcommand{\mycommand}[2]{%
  \@namedef{mycommand@store@#1}{#2}%
}
```

This might then say be used to save some user information: I'll use e-mail addresses but it could be anything

```
\mycommand{Joe Bloggs}{joe.blogs@some.domain}
```

If you have a bigger set up doing this, say storing several pieces of data about several 'keys', then using `\@namedef` keeps things a lot more readable than using `\expandafter\def\csname ...`.
    \mycommand{A. N. Other}{another@place.com}

Comment: Is there a way I can make tex show me the expansions step by step? Also, can you please give an example were `\@namedef` is usefull?

Comment: @ted In your addition to the question, the 'direct' example uses a different counter name to the one in the `\def`. I suspect that one of these is simply not defined: can you check (or provide a full MWE)?

Comment: @ted You can use the `trace` package to control printing of tracing information, or simply can add `\tracingall` for a reasonably complete listing. (The `trace` package prints even more info than `\tracingall`.)

Comment: @ted You can't use `{}` in a `\csname` to stop space skipping: it's an expansion not a typsetting context, and so the `{}` remains. You need a space: `\expandafter\usebox\csname prefix\alph{c}\endcsname`.